# Oracle R Enterprise: ore.corr and ore.freq return different results for pearson correlation

Tags: r, oracle, statistics, data-mining, enterprise

Can somebody explain me why ore.corr and ore.freq returns different results for pearson correlation?

my ore.freq code:

```
ore.iris = ore.push(iris);
ct = ore.crosstab(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, ore.iris)
ore.freq(ct,stats = "PCORR")
```

it returns

```
 METHOD      FREQ  DF PVALUE               DESCR GROUP
1  PCORR 0.8035882 714      1 Pearson Correlation     1
```

and my ore.corr code:

```
ore.iris = ore.push(iris);
ore.corr(ore.iris, var = "Sepal.Length,Petal.Width ")
```

it returns

```
           ROW         COL PEARSON_T PEARSON_P PEARSON_DF
1 Sepal.Length Petal.Width 0.8179411         0        148
```

I think two results must be equal to each others. Please give me explaination.

Comment: Try the same without the Oracle overhead, but in real R. What do you get?

Comment: Like anything that is barely ever used, I would not be surprised to see bugs in Oracles R hack. I'd use the real R instead.

Comment: With R, cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Width) return 0.8179411, same as result of ore.corr.